# IntellijIDEA plugin development - Add custom maven repository to Android project build.gradle file

Tags: android, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want programmatically add a maven repository to `build.gradle` file.

Was able to add a dependency using `DependenciesModel.addArtifact()` but similar method is not available in `RepositoriesModel`.

Is there any way to add a new repository (eg. `UrlBasedRepositoryModel()` ) to a `RepositoriesModel`?

Comment: Also asked in [the forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000151484-Add-custom-maven-repository-to-Android-project-build-gradle-file-).

Comment: Looks like there is no such API. :/

Comment: @AKT Did you find a workaround?

Comment: @Jimmy I looked at the source code and there is no such method. Base model for repository only have a method to retrieve repositories list. Might have to write a parser.

Comment: @AKT It would've been nice, I saw someone opened a ticket so maybe they will implement it in the future. Thanks for getting back to me!